# JS created input not submiting to php

Tags: javascript, php

I am running into an odd issue and unable to resolve it for a couple of hrs now.

I have a simple js which create an HTML input array but it's not been submitted while rest of form works fine Please advice.

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post">   

<input type="text" name="first_name">
<div id="array">
// genrated array using js  results empty in php raw 
<p><input type="hidden" name="arrayselected[]" value="13">test</p>
<p><input type="hidden" name="arrayselected[]" value="4">test</p>
</div>
</form>
```

while demo.php raw is showing the only first_name and not arrayselected[]

Edit 1 Javascript

```
function addarray() {
  var getvalue = document.getElementById("selector").value; // a user selected value that is outside the form 
  var gettext = $('#selector').find(":selected").text();
  var verify = document.getElementsByName('productselected[]');

  var isitok = '1';

  for (var i = 0; i <verify.length; i++) {

     var vcheck = verify[i];

          if(getvalue ==vcheck.value) {
             var isitok='0';
             alert('Already Selected');
           }

   }
   if(isitok=='1') {
     document.getElementById("array").innerHTML+= '<p><input type="hidden" name="arrayselected[]" value="' + arrayselected + '"/>' + arraytext + '</p>' ;

                        }
                    }


                </script>
```

Edit 2 - No Form is not submit by Javascript

Edit 3 - As of now i am not even trying to get the value all i am doing on php side is

```
<?php
 var_dump($_POST);
 var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));        
 $array=$_POST['arrayselected'];
 ?>
```

Comment: Please share the code used to generate the additional field, as well as the PHP used to determine that it was not set.

Comment: Also, is the form submit being handled by javascript? If so, provide the relevant code.

Comment: Don't forget to include your PHP

Comment: Please provide the PHP output as well.